# Should Generic URL Decoding Functions Handle "+" Chars or Just "%20" etc. Chars?

Tags: http, vbscript, decoding

I am wondering if a generic URL Decoding function should handle the "`+`" character (space) in addition to all of the e.g. "`%20`" etc. encodings?

There is no specific use case as of yet.

Is there any spec that would be appropriate to reference here?

I am doing it in `VBScript` (but that is not relevant to my question I believe) and I have two versions, one which would handle the "`+`" by replacing it with a "" (space) ...

```
Public Function decode(s)
    s = replace(s, "+", " ")
    For i = 1 To Len(s)
        If Mid(s, i, 1) = "%" Then
            decode = decode & Chr("&H" & Mid(s, i+1, 2))
            i = i + 2
        Else
            decode = decode & Mid(s, i, 1)
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

...and one which does not:

```
Public Function decode(s)
    For i = 1 To Len(s)
        If Mid(s, i, 1) = "%" Then
            decode = decode & Chr("&H" & Mid(s, i+1, 2))
            i = i + 2
        Else
            decode = decode & Mid(s, i, 1)
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's supposed to be generic: no. The role of "+" is very specific to HTML forms and has nothing to do with generic URI handling.

Comment: Thanks. What documentation should I look toward  to support your answer?

Comment: RFC 3986 and the HTML5 spec.

Comment: Thank you sir. Exactly what I was looking for.